# How database server can automatically update

Tags: php, mysql, database, server

I am making a game and i want to do this:
every 30 minutes every player must gain coins (online players and offline players too!).
So there will be a way that the database will automatically update the columns after 30 minutes and will add to every player some coins.

Comment: RTFM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: thanks (you are fast)! i will try it. i am new so some stuff i don't even know how to search them.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to create an event like so

```
CREATE EVENT addcoins
ON SCHEDULE AT '2014-11-12 12:00:00' + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
DO
  UPDATE `player_tbl` SET `player_tbl`.`coins` = `player_tbl`.`coins` + 1;
```

Comment: thanks! this is amazing and so easy. i was trying to find it long time.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use a cronjob - you can create a script (e.g. in PHP) on your server then create a cronjob to execute the script every 30 minutes.